# Laravel - Eloquent join query not working

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm doing a simple `join` query of `job_roles` and `operations` table.
The `fk` is the column `job_role_id` of `operations` references to the column `id` of `job_roles`.

Output that I need is get the total count of data from `operations` where `operations.structure_cost` is not equal to `job_roles.cost_type`

I have a working query created in `MySQL Workbench` using this code below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total
   FROM
job_roles t1
   RIGHT JOIN
operations t2 ON t2.job_role_id = t1.id
   WHERE
t2.structure_cost != t1.cost_type
t2.master_id = 1; ### get operations only for auth user
```

Below is my query in `Laravel` that don't work. `Count` that I'm getting in below data example is `3` which is `wrong`, Count should return `1` as what is indicated in the `where clause`

[image]

table name: job_roles

[image]

table name: operations

[image]

Comment: Please paste the code as text, not as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third parameter of `where` function is used as a value and not as a column name. Use `whereRaw` function

Comment: Don't even need to use `whereRaw()`; Laravel has a `whereColumn()` method: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses (scroll down a bit)

Comment: Thanks @Nick!  I'm trying working on using `DB::raw` but no good. This works.